# Analytic function on the right half plane, value at s=0?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have an analytic function ( Laplace of a time domain function), F(s), on the right half plane. It is zero every where except at s=0. Can anything be concluded about F(0)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to use [Mellin's inverse formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Laplace_transform), integrating over a vertical line to the right of $0$. Since the integrand it identically zero, we conclude that $f(t)=0$ for all $t$. It then follows that $F=0$ everywhere.